# Docker : failed to compute cache key

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image for my sample-go app.
I am running it from the sample-app folder itself and using the goland editor's terminal. But the build is failing and giving me certain errors.

**My docker file looks like this:**

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src/build
WORKDIR /src/build

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata ca-certificates

COPY ./configs /configs
COPY main /main

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/main"]
```

**command for building:**

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain  - < Dockerfile
```

**Error And Logs:**

```
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:8bb9ee83603259cf748d90ce42602f12527fa720d7417da22799b2ad4e503497
#1 transferring dockerfile: 222B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:f93d938488588cd0e0a94d9d343fe69dcfd28d0cb1da95ad7aab00aac50235c3
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest
#3 sha256:13549c58a76bcb5dac9d52bc368a8fb6b5cf7659f94e3fa6294917b85546978d
#3 DONE 0.0s

#10 [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest
#10 sha256:d20daa00e252bfb345a1b4f53b6bb332aafe702d8de5e583a76fcd09ba7ea1c1
#10 CACHED

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 sha256:0f7a8a6082a837c139acc2855e1b745bba9f28cc96709d45cd0b7be42442c0e8
#7 transferring context: 2B done
#7 DONE 0.0s

#4 [2/6] RUN mkdir -p /src/build
#4 sha256:b9fa3007a44471d47414dd29b3ff07ead6af28ede820a2b4bae0ce84cf2c5a83
#4 CACHED

#5 [3/6] WORKDIR /src/build
#5 sha256:b2ec58a365fdd74c4f9030b0caff2e2225eea33617da306678ad037fce675388
#5 CACHED

#6 [4/6] RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata ca-certificates
#6 sha256:0966097abf956d5781bc2330d49cf715cd52c3807e8fedfff07dec50907ff03b
#6 CACHED

#9 [6/6] COPY main /main
#9 sha256:f4b81960427c014a020361bea0903728f289e1d796892fe0adc6409434f3ca76
#9 ERROR: "/main" not found: not found

#8 [5/6] COPY ./configs /configs
#8 sha256:630f272dd60dd307f40dbbdaef277ee0dfc24b71fa11e10a3b8efd64d3c05086
#8 ERROR: "/configs" not found: not found

#4 [2/6] RUN mkdir -p /src/build
#4 sha256:b9fa3007a44471d47414dd29b3ff07ead6af28ede820a2b4bae0ce84cf2c5a83
#4 DONE 0.2s
------
 > [5/6] COPY ./configs /configs:
------
------
 > [6/6] COPY main /main:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/main" not found: not found
```

PS: I am not able to find where is the problem? Help Please

Comment: You have to work relative to your set WORKDIR and verify that your image that has been built has the name 'main'. If you have other declarations it also might default `sample-go` or whatever has been configured.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I missed the folder entry in .dockerignore file. Do something like that.

```
**/*
!docker-images
!configs
!main
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic mistake.

- `COPY ./configs /configs`: copy the folder `configs` from the **host** to the **Docker image**.
- `COPY main /main`: copy the executable file `main` from the **host** to the **Docker image**.

The problems are:

- The base Docker images do not have these folders `/configs`, `/main`. You must create them manually (Docker understood your command this way).
- But I have some advice:

  - Create 2 Docker images for 2 purposes: build, production.
  - Copy the source code into Docker builder image which is use for building your app.
  - Copy necessary output files from the Docker builder image into the Docker production image.

Answer (score 2):

The two folders `/main` and `/configs` does not exist.

The `COPY` command can't copy into this folders.

**1. Solution**

Create the folders on build

```
RUN mkdir -p /main

RUN mkdir -p /configs
```

And than use `COPY`

**2. Solution**

1. Try to build without `COPY` and `CMD`
2. Than `run` the the new image
3. `exec` into running container with `bash` or `sh`
4. Create the folders
5. Exit `exec` container
6. Create a new image of the running container with docker run `commit`
7. Stop the container and delete it
8. Build again with your new image and include `COPY` and `CMD`

Comment: @Umang-Mundhra it run's now how is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was the connected vpn/proxy network from my machine.
It worked after I disconnecting the vpn/proxy network.

Answer (score 0):

From official [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#copy):

> If you build using STDIN (docker build - < somefile), there is no
> build context, so COPY can't be used.

You can use `docker build .`

Answer (score -3):

write in this manner.

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 5002


# Create and set the working directory
WORKDIR /

# Copy the Flask app code into the container 
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt   

# Install dependencies from the requirements.txt    
file RUN pip install -r requirements.txt   

COPY . .    

# Expose the port for Flask 

EXPOSE 5002   

# Start the Flask application CMD    
["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5002"]
```